# How to crawl entire Wikipedia?

Tags: java, web-crawler, wikipedia, websphinx

I've tried WebSphinx application.

I realize if I put wikipedia.org as the starting URL, it will not crawl further.

Hence, how to actually crawl the entire Wikipedia? Can anyone gimme some guidelines? Do I need to specifically go and find those URLs and put multiple starting URLs?

Anyone has suggestions of good website with the tutorial on usng WebSphinx's API?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If your goal is to crawl all of Wikipedia, you might want to look at the available database dumps. See http://download.wikimedia.org/.

Comment: +1. Crawling Wikipedia through HTTP is rude and puts a lot of extra load on the servers.

Comment: @GregHewgill, that's a pretty assumptive statement.  It really depends on how rapidly you crawl the site, whether you respect the robots.txt directives and what you'd consider "a lot of extra load" to mean.  According to wikipedia "Friendly, low-speed bots are welcome viewing article pages, but not dynamically-generated pages please." - http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt  
Crawlers typically aren't designed for parsing wikipedia-specific xml documents filled with wiki markup, so creating a separate system to parse dated xml dumps just for wikipedia.com seems silly.

Comment: I don't get it: if friendly crawling is allowed, why do they disallow such a number of crawlers in robots.txt ?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure but maybe WEbSphinx's UserAgent is blocked by wikipedia's robots.txt

http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using the Wikipedia database dump mentioned above, you can use Wikipedia's API for executing queries, such as retrieving 100 random articles.

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-*Lists#random*.2F_rn](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query_-_Lists#random_.2F_rn)

Answer (score 2):

I think you couldn't choose the required configuration for that. Switch to advanced, crawl the subdomain, unlimit the page size and time.

However, **WebSphinx** probably can't crawl the whole **Wikipedia**, it slows down with bigger data and eventually stops near 200mb of memory is used. I recommend you [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/), [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/index.html) and [Crawler4j](http://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start with a random article, and then crawl all articles you can get to from that starting one. When that search tree has been exhausted, start with  a new random article. You could seed your searches with terms you think will lead to the most articles, or start with the featured article on the front page.

Another question: Why didn't WebSphinx crawl further? Does wikipedia block bots that identify as 'WebSphinx'?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/), a structured version of Wikipedia.